# Is there a function to get a minimum or the Value in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I want to select all values from a table. One column is a **SIGNED INTEGER** that also contains negative numbers. I want set a minimum for this column (1) while selecting. Like this:

If the value is **20** i want to get **20**.

If the value is **1**, I want to get **1**.

But when the value smaller than **1** is, then I want only to get **1**.

Is there a function that allows me to do this? It should only be 1 command because i want to use it in PHP with mysqli!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function:

```
SELECT GREATEST(-1,1); -> 1
SELECT GREATEST(20,1); -> 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

```
select case when your_column >= 0 
            then your_column
            else 1
       end
from your_table
```

or [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
select if(your_column >= 0, your_column, 1)
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <colname> < 1 THEN 1 ELSE <colname> END CASE
```

If it's less than one, it will return one. If it's larger than one, it will return the value that it is.

See more here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html